# Get Facebook friends using email and password

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to get the facebook friends email ids of a user providing his login email id and password. That is, if we enter the facebook login email id and password we need to get the  friends from facebook. So far i was only able to get the examples which uses Api_Key and Api_Secret. Even the Graph api is using Access Token. Is there any way to access the friends using email id and password? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This is against Facebook's [Terms of Service.](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)  Specifically policy I.2:

> You must not include functionality that proxies, requests or collects
>   Facebook usernames or passwords.

Also, you would be required to use the Facebook API which does not provide access to friends email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ask your users to authenticate using the Facebook API. You shouldn't be collecting email and passwords on behalf of users. However, if you ask for offline access, then when you do this, you can access the data any time.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses oAuth, so you and your application will never see the password of the user that you are getting permission for. oAuth (used by Twitter and Google as well) requires a bit of a handshake to get authenticated, but once you do, you can get permission from the user to do whatever you want, as long as they accept.

Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login for more on how Facebook does authentication.